# Node.js : Nginx won't serve static content

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am trying to server static content via nginx on my node.js app. For the seemingly simple and obvious setup, I am not able to route the static content via nginx. With this line :

```
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
                    access_log off;
                    expires max;
    }
```

nginx does not server any static content (js, css, images) - but on removing this I see that static contents are displayed. 
On Node side, I am using express and jade.

nginx.conf:
    https://gist.github.com/3331669

default:
    https://gist.github.com/3331674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
location ~  \.(jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}
```

Comment: No luck. One thing is that I am running nginx as www-data user while my app's permissions are for root:root - is that causing this? If I run nginx with 'root' things work fine. Are there any problems running nginx as root ?

Comment: It's a bad idea to run things as root unless they really have to be. Set the octal permissions for those static files to 644 (i.e. readable by other) so that www-data user can read them.

Comment: If you run things as root, any vulnerability in your app could destroy your server (since the exploit would run with root privileges)

Comment: True. Even if I set permission to 644 to /public folder for www-datda I get the same error. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Sorry, for files, set permissions to 644. For folders, set permissions to 755

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
location ~*  .*\.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html?)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}
```

Comment: Still same issue after I disable assets from express.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
location ~* .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        root /var/www/yoursitename/public;
    }
```